# Save an indeterminate number of days of the week in a MongoDb

Tags: database, mongodb, date, mongoose, field

I need to save an indeterminate number of days of the week in a MongoDb field and I don't know if this is possible, I explain, I have an application where the days of the week where that subject has classes will be saved, At the time of registering the subject, it must be possible to put the number of classes that will be per week and on what days of the week the classes will be given, the thing is that each subject can have one, two, three, four or up to five classes a week and I don't know how to handle that,
I was thinking of saving a string in the field that says something like "Monday - Tuesday - Friday". I accept suggestions. Thanks and regards.

Comment: can you add an example? for better understanding @Gastón Khouri

Comment: Hello @rohanraj, an example of what I say is the following, I have a form in which you select the days of the week in which that subject is going to be taught, they can be from one to 5, that is, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday or Friday, I need to save which options they selected in the database, I hope I have made myself understood